# How can I increase max_input_vars in Linux Ubuntu /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

In windows to increase the `max_input_var` you need to go to `php.ini` and look for it. But now since I transferred my laravel project in linux ubuntu now I'm having a problem with the `max_input_vars`.

I tried to find the `max_input_vars` line of code in the `php.ini` that is located in my:

`/opt/lamppt/etc/php,ini`

But failed to find it. Some says if it doesn't exists on the `php.ini` I just need to add some line of codes there to setup the `max_input_vars`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To increase `max_input_vars` try this in your `php.ini` :

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 2000);
```

Or u also add code in `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value max_input_vars 2000
```